# Is there a book that discusses General Relativity in terms of Modern Differential Geometry?

Tags: general-relativity, mathematical-physics, soft-question, resource-recommendations, differential-geometry

All of the physics books that I've seen which discuss General Relativity do so in terms of coordinates - the tensor calculus - even though the naturally relevant entities are invariant under general coordinate change. Modern Differential geometry dispenses with coordinates.

Is there a book out there that discusses GR wholly in terms of differential geometry?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15002/2451

Comment: I'd say this is adequately covered in the duplicate link.  Of the references in there, Sachs and Wu takes a very coordinate free approach.

Comment: I strongly suggest heeding at least some of Ron's answer there. Physicist's notation is **not** as coordinate centric as thought by mathematicians who've never used it. Used properly, coordinate invariance is manifest in all your Einstein-notated equations. Every GR physicist fully understands differential geometry, but we *choose* a notation that actually enables physical problems to be solved, and all physical problems *must* be cast into a particular basis in the end anyway.