# Good resources for understanding inflationary cosmology

Tags: cosmology, resource-recommendations, cosmological-inflation

I'm currently trying to self study inflationary cosmology and am finding it difficult to find good resources which explain the motivation behind such theories while providing all the mathematical details.

Does anyone know any good text or resource on inflationary cosmology?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159120/2451

Comment: Adding to the references already given in the related question and the answer of @Diferansiyel. A few days ago some realy nice lecture notes on Inflation came on the ArXiv: http://arxiv.org/abs/1609.00716. They present a pretty nice introduction to inflation and some advanced concepts.

Comment: I’m putting a bounty on in the hopes of getting a canonical answer, or at least one with post-2000 references.

Comment: There is the "Visual GR" series, with this episode on cosmology:
http://physicsisnotweird.com/general-relativity-part-6-space-expands/

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to understand scalar field models of dark energy which are motivated by inflationary cosmology. The motivation is that we may also explain the late-time acceleration using scalar fields(e.g quintessence, k-essence etc.). Anyway the following textbook was useful for me.

[*Cosmological Inflation and Large-Scale Structure*](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139175180) by Andrew R. Liddle & David H. Lyth (2000, Cambridge University Press).

And, I also recommend the other lecture notes & documents prepared by Liddle. For example [An introduction to cosmological inflation](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9901124) (arXiv:astro-ph/9901124)

His materials are highly pedagogical and have rigorous math.

Answer (score 0):

I thought Weinberg's book on Cosmology is very instructive. Most of it I think is explained very lucidly in the first chapter of the book - just make sure to skip all the standard candle shananigans, which is boring.