# Any good Cosmology book recommendations (undergrad->postgrad level)

Tags: cosmology, resource-recommendations, education, cosmological-inflation

I am looking to study cosmology at graduate level. Does any one recommend any introductory and comprehensive books for cosmology principles? I am interested in the maths too but I really want a book that introduces the principles and concepts first, to then dig deeper with the maths later.

Comment: I've seen Andrew R. Liddle's book "An Introduction to Modern Cosmology"

https://blackwells.co.uk/bookshop/product/9781118502143?gC=5a105e8b&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIipjelOP26QIVzbTtCh3mOwIvEAQYASABEgLlXPD_BwE

recommended. It may not dig into the maths in the sense of differential geometry though, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: You can try Ryden

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159120/2451 and links therein.