# Introduction to Cosmology Resources?

Tags: cosmology, resource-recommendations

Are there any good alternatives to Barbara Ryden's *Introduction to Cosmology*?

I'm currently taking an undergraduate cosmology course using this textbook and I'm not a huge fan of it. In my opinion, the derivations and explanations aren't thorough enough, and it's not ideal to keep searching for different resources when needing a further explanation on a topic.

Comment: If it's for an undergraduate course, asking your instructor is likely to be most productive. Ryden's book is great for undergraduates; any more thorough book is likely to be masters level or higher.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159120/2451 and links therein.