# Book Recommendation on Math needed for General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, conformal-field-theory

Today, I had to do an exercise that talked about conformal geometry and after spending a ridiculous amount time searching for it in General Relativity books I couldn't find it. In books like Ray D'Inverno, Schutz and Sean Carroll they state the theorems, but never prove them, so I am asking if you could recommend any book on conformal geometry and whatever math you think is going to be essential to understand really well General Relativity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mathematically-oriented Treatment of General Relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15002/mathematically-oriented-treatment-of-general-relativity)

Comment: Not quite. The O'Neil book doesn't approach conformal geometry as I need, but the Marcus Kriele book is one book that I'm gonna save for the future!