# Book Suggestion for GR

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations

I need to hear suggestions on some text books on General Relativity that is self-contained, at least containing the sufficient material to go till Einstein Field equations, Schwarzschild solution and some applications of GR. It is for post graduate mathematics students. Content that can be covered in one semester.

Comment: You say it’s for math students, so if they have a good background in differential geometry, then Wald or Hawking and Ellis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mathematically-oriented Treatment of General Relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15002/168783)