Books that approach General Relativity via differential forms, without coordinates
Does someone know about some books about differential geometry applied to General Relativity that are written using the language of differential forms, fiber bundles, & spin connection, and not written using the coordinates?

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15002/2451 and links therein.
