# Looking for lecture videos that follow Arnold's Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian-formalism

I'm an undergrad and I'm looking for lecture videos (on youtube and such) that follow this textbook.
My course roughly follows it, but glosses over some mathematical details that I feel would be useful to me for proper intuitive understanding of what's actually going on.

Any recommendations welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1601/2451 and links therein.