# Good books for understanding Lagrangian formulation of classical fields?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, classical-field-theory

I want to understand Lagrangian formulation for classical fields and apply it to understand constrained dynamics. Currently I am referring to "A modern approach: Classical Mechanics" by ECG Sudarshan, N Mukunda

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/135726/2451

Comment: Try ``Structure and interpretation of Classical Mechanics'' by Gerald Jay Sussman and Jack Wisdom