# Book Recommendation for Lagrangian and Hamiltonian Mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian-formalism

I'm looking for a book recommendation for an undergraduate level textbook covering Lagrangian and Hamiltonian Mechanics. I'll be taking the second course on classical mechanics in the upcoming term. Ideally, I'd like a textbook that -- in addition to focusing on the application of the principles to solve physical systems, as mostly done in "$\text{PHY}: 101$" -- focuses on the theoretical aspects as well -- Poisson Brackets etc. Most of the textbooks I have seen seem to focus only on the former.

Since ideas in Hamiltonian and Lagrangian Mechanics pop up everywhere -- from non relativitic QM to QFT -- I'd appreciate if someone can recommend an undergraudate level textbook that caters to both of the aforementioned criteria.

Comment: Duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/135726/

Answer (score 0):

I personally like Classical Mechanics by John Taylor. It gives some good examples and also is a pretty easy read. I still use it as a reference for a good majority of classical mechanics.