# Book recommendation for relativistic classical mechanics

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian-formalism

I need some good resource recommendations for the relativistic hamiltonian mechanics under special theory of relativity, with a good discussion on relativistic Hamilton-Jacobi formulation.

Comment: Books that we like you may not...  See https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111/207455

Comment: Or this one : https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/135726/207455

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/762514/2451