# What are some books that teach to apply Lagrangian methods on simple systems of Physics I?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, education

I want to find a book that teaches simple Kinematics problems but use both Newtonian and Analytical method, and maybe draw parallel between them. Is there such a reference?

Comment: There is a good reason why theoretical mechanics is not taught in elementary books: one needs to have a good grasp of Newtonian physics (and math) to study deeper theory.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/135726/2451 and links therein.

Comment: goldstein is good