# Good resources for revision/learning of classical mechanics and electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I am a first year PhD student in Physics. My M.Sc classes were all online due to covid and I did pretty bad in managing classes. Thus my electrodynamics knowledge is effectively upto B.Sc level(say Griffiths). I want to now study M.Sc level electrodynamics from scratch. Also I am fairly weak at classical mechanics, specifically in Newtonian mechanics, rigid body motion, angular momentum etc. I would also like to revise some advanced topics like action-angle variables, symplectic geometry etc. Can anyone please suggest good books/resources for learning and revising these (both theory+problems for practice)? For electrodynamics, I have read Jackson little bit but didn't find it much friendly, so it would be helpful if there are some other easier books/notes that deal with M.Sc level electrodynamics.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142419/2451 and links therein.